# StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, stripe-payments

I am trying to initiate a payment from stripe but its failing again. Below is my code. Please help me why is this happening.

Nodejs version:
v18.7.0

NPM version:
8.4.1

Stripe_api.js

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { items, email } = req.body;

  const transformedItems = items.map(item => ({
    description: item.description,
    quantity: 1,
    price_data: {
      currency: 'GBP',
      unit_amount: item.price * 100,
      product_data: {
        name: item.title,
        images:[item.image]
      }
    },
  }));

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    shipping_rates: ['shr_1Lo5yeSJ4Tf************'],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ['GB', 'US', 'CA'],
    },
    line_items: transformedItems,
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,
    metadata: {
      email,
      images: JSON.stringify(items.map((item)=> item.image))
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json({ id: session.id});
};
```

checkout.js

```
function Checkout() {
  const items = useSelector(selectItems);
  const total = useSelector(selectTotal);
  const [session] = useSession();
    const createCheckoutSession = async() => {
        const stripe = await stripePromise;

    //checkout session
    const checkoutSession = await axios.post(
      '/api/Stripe/create-checkout-session',
      {
        items: items,
        email: session.user.email,
      }     
    );
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id,
      });
  
      if (result.error) {
        alert(result.error.message);
      }
}
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100">
      <Header />
      <main className="lg:flex max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto">
        {/* Left*/}
        <div>
          <div className="flex flex-col p-5 space-y-10 bg-white">
            <h1 className="text-3xl border-b pb-4">
              {items.length === 0
                ? "Your Amazon Basket is empty"
                : "Shopping Basket"}
            </h1>

            {items.map((item, i) => (
              <CheckoutProduct
                key={i}
                id={item.id}
                title={item.title}
                rating={item.rating}
                price={item.price}
                description={item.description}
                category={item.category}
                image={item.image}
                hasPrime={item.hasPrime}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          {items.length > 0 && (
            <>
              <h2 className="whitespace-nowrap">
                Subtotal ({items.length} items):
                <span className="font-bold">
                  <Currency quantity={total} currency="GBP" />
                </span>
              </h2>

              <button
                role="link"
                onClick = {createCheckoutSession}
                disabled={!session}
                className={`button mt-2 ${
                  !session &&
                  "from-gray-300 to-gray-500 border-gray-200 text-gray-300 cursor-not-allowed"
                }`}
              >
                {!session ? "Sign in to checkout" : "Proceed to checkout"}
              </button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checkout;
```

Data is loading perfectly by console.log(items)

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ',
    price: 22.3,
    description: 'Slim-fitting style, contrast raglan long sleeve, three-button henley placket, light weight & soft fabric for breathable and comfortable wearing. And Solid stitched shirts with round neck made for durability and a great fit for casual fashion wear and diehard baseball fans. The Henley style round neckline includes a three-button placket.',
    category: "men's clothing",
    image: 'https://****/****/71-3HjGNDUL._AC_SY879._SX._UX._SY._UY_.jpg',
    hasPrime: false
  }
]
```

ERROR

StripeInvalidRequestError: You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more information.
at StripeError.generate (C:\Users\shikshgu\shopping site\Amazon\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:36:16)
at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (C:\Users\shikshgu\shopping site\Amazon\node_modules\stripe\lib\StripeResource.js:201:35)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
message: 'You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`, `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migrating-prices for more information.',
request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_28SN2DhsGvhHVF?t=1665815298',
type: 'invalid_request_error',
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Sat, 15 Oct 2022 06:28:18 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '470',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': '849332d0-1d08-4052-bc3a-3c92b503d4cd',
'original-request': 'req_28SN2DhsGvhHVF',
'request-id': 'req_28SN2DhsGvhHVF',
'stripe-should-retry': 'false',
'stripe-version': '2022-08-01',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
statusCode: 400,
requestId: 'req_28SN2DhsGvhHVF'
},
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
code: undefined,
doc_url: undefined,

Comment: Your code is passing `description` for each hash in `line_items` and this is not supported today. You have to remove it for your code to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

When using `create` API you can only use `line_items.price` or `line_items.price_data`. Refer [Create a Session.create](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items)

Copy `Price ID` from your stripe product and put it.

Get this price ID

[image: Here is price id in product]

Put it in `price` of `line_items`
[image]

*this is my python function, yours work similarly*